# Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'UIImage'

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code,

```
self.plistModification(urlStr: urlString, uploadedImage:nil )
```

May I know how to assign an image value to nil.

my plistModification function is given below, the uploadedImage value (UIImage)changed every time whenever I call the function.

```
   func plistModification(urlStr : String , uploadedImage : UIImage)
{
    self.activityView.isHidden = false
    SBNetworkManager().getDetails(sortType: "", URLString: urlStr, param: "") { (dictList, error) in


            self.imageUpload(imageData: uploadedImage)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.activityView.isHidden = true
            }
            if self.flag == 1
            {
                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
            }

        }
        else
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.activityView.isHidden = true
                if self.flag == 1
                {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: dictList!["status_message"]as? String, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
                    })
                    alert.addAction(alertAction)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please add function code also

Comment: What is `plistModification(urlStr:, uploadedImage:)` ? How is it declared? Who wrote it? Are you allowed to modify it?

Comment: `nil` can only be passed as an argument if the parameter is an `Optional` - in your case, that would be `UIImage?`, while your `uploadedImage` is actually `UIImage`. You need to rewrite `plistModification` to expect `uploadedImage` to be an optional.

Comment: I update my code anyone can you please check that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an empty image just like this

```
  self.plistModification(urlStr: urlString, uploadedImage:UIImage() )
```

or You can set your method argument as optional like

```
   func plistModification(urlStr: String, uploadedImage:UIImage?)
```

in the second option, you can pass nil value

Comment: @sazidThanks the second one help me.:)

Comment: Just to add to Sazid's answer, if you set a default value to the function declaration you don't have to pass a value at all during function call.
"func plistModification(urlStr: String, uploadedImage:UIImage? = nil)" and then "self.plistModification(urlStr: urlString)"

Answer (score 1):

```
    self.plistModification(urlStr: urlString)
//OR

    self.plistModification(urlStr: urlString, uploadedImage:imageData)
    //it may be image or nil


    func plistModification(urlStr: string, uploadedImage:UIImage? = nil){

    }
```

Instead of passing new image object or nil to function, you can handle it at function level declare parameter as optional with default value. So when you need to pass nil then don't write than parameter in function call

Comment: I call the function in three times in a page, and the value of uploadedImage changes whenever I call the function.

Comment: @AngelFSyrus no issue then call it and pass data whatever you get, nil or image